# OneNote 2013 is not showing math equations. The variables show up as boxes

Tags: microsoft-onenote, office365

So I have installed OneNote 2013 and the Mathematics add-on for OneNote and Word. Yet when I try to install an equation in OneNote (alt + +) and type in any variables all that I get is a box, implying it can't read or display the character. Also, sadly, when I try the same thing in Word it will cause Word to instantly crash.

Here are some things I have done.
•I have uninstalled and reinstalled Office 365.
•I have repaired my office installation, but using a quick repair and a longer repair.
•I have searched online, but have not found a solution.
•Other installs on other computers work just fine.

Any ideas on next steps? I am a math teacher and use OneNote for all of my lessons. School starts next week. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like I solved my own problem.  The font file cambria.ttc (which includes both cambria and cambria math fonts) was not installed in my C:\\Windows\fonts folder.  Weird.  So I installed it.  I have the font on another computer.  I have never seen something like that before.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice given by Bryan Davis and searched my font folder.  Sure enough, I did not have Cambria/Cambria math installed (bizarre).

I did a quick google search and found the cambria.ttc file I was missing, installed it, and restarted OneNote.  Equations work now.

Comment: https://cs.fit.edu/code/projects/ndworld/repository/changes/Resources/Fonts/cambria.ttc?rev=11 was the link, for anyone curious